# Detecting maximum memory bandwidth at kernel level

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, memory-bandwidth

I'm looking for a way to detect the maximum memory bandwidth at the kernel level in Linux. There are some ways to measure the memory bandwidth that each task is using, however, I couldn't find a way that estimates the total memory bandwidth of the system at the kernel level (or kernel module). Is there any way to get this info at the kernel level?

Comment: `sudo dmidecode -t memory`

Comment: This is user space command. I'm looking for a kernel solution. @stark